# how to adjust big line address in responsive site?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

how to adjust big line address in responsive site? Check this link and tell me."http://demo.proudtobeawoman.in/"

Comment: you will have to break the big address line into smaller pieces

Comment: ok bt i want that address will be set in phone like line by line.

Comment: I am not sure if SO member should answering a question where a user who is facing problem, does not even bother to describe the problem. What is problem you are facing, what have you tried so far, post the HTML/CSS/JS and let us know where are you stuck?

Answer (score -1):

Once you have the pieces (let's say you wrapped in a `<p>`) then you can use bootstrap or flexbox to style it. I will say lets go with flexbox so I will do the following:

```
    <style>

        #parent{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
        #parent p{
            flex: 0 1 auto;
            min-width: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="parent">
        <p> the first line</p>
        <p> the second line</p>
        <p> the third line</p>
        <p> the fourth line</p>
    </div>

</body>
```

Just apply some modification to the min-width as per your design and you should be good to go.

Comment: Hi there. Your answers look quite helpful, but I'd say they could do with proof-reading - the missing `<p>` tag and the missing HTML code here were nothing like you intended them, since they were not formatted. Additionally, it seems that you're writing entirely in lower case. Please be aware that we tend to ask for reference-quality writing here - if you can double-check everything before posting, that is much appreciated.